# One hashbyte value for all strings in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

I need to create a hash for a whole set of rows in one column. So I have e.g. 1000 rows, but the result of the select must be just 1 row (hash).

Data can be like:

1. row: 'Hi'
2. row:'all'

and I need a hash for: 'Hiall' not one hash for 'Hi' and 2nd hash for 'all' (which MSSQL still returns to me)

It works in Oracle like this:

```
with source as(  
select text as data from table
)
select ORA_HASH(LISTAGG(data) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data))  from source
```

But I really do not know how to make it in MSSQL.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
with source as(  
select text as data from table
)
select hashbytes('MD5',stuff((data),len(data),0,(data)))from source;
```

also tried this:

```
select hashbytes('MD5',stuff((text),len(text),0,(text)))  from table
```

and many other variants, but nothing works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the values together using:

```
select (select col
        from table t
        for xml path(''), type
       ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

You can these make this the argument to `hashbytes()`:

```
select hashbytes ((select col
                   from table t
                   for xml path(''), type
                  ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
                 )
```

Note:  you might want an `order by` clause if you care about the order of the string concatenation.

Comment: thank you so much :) I have one more question..do you know which hash function is used in Oracle in ORA_HASH? I mean if it is SHA1, MD5 or what...because I need to compare hashes from MSSQL and Oracle...

Comment: @neliCZka . . . The Oracle documentation should explain that clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it all to one string by outputting for xml. Then you can hash the result. Make sure, you don't have a columnname. Here's a silly example...

```
        SELECT ''+ name 
        FROM sys.all_columns
        WHERE object_id = (
               SELECT object_id
               FROM sys.all_objects
               WHERE object_id = object_id('sys.all_columns')
               ) FOR     XML PATH ('')
```